# Creating a tooltip on word(s) in a text editor (Google Docs) using JavaScript/CSS

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-docs, google-docs-api

**Intro:**
I'm working with Google Docs and have been trying (and struggling) to create a tooltip that pops up on selected (highlighted with cursor) words after the click of a button, for the purpose of creating notes for studying.

For example, if I have the words "Dynamic Programming" and I want to add the definition of it to the instances of "Dynamic Programming" so that when I hover/click on it, the definition will appear and I won't have to constantly scroll around or CTRL+F for it.

**My question is** if there is any advice on how to attach a tooltip to the selected text. I'm thinking of maybe creating a `class="tooltip"` and altering the inner HTML to include this class using xpath selection, but I'm struggling to put this idea into place. Are there any suggestions for how to approach this issue?

I've tried altering the selected text using the [Document.ExecCommand()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/execCommand), like bolding it but there are no results. I see that this command is deprecated but I'm not sure what else I can use in its place. I wanted to use it's `insertHTML()`.

**My code so far:**

I'm currently able to get the user's text selection (to attach the tooltip to), although it doesn't work entirely as planned. Even if you select only one word, it returns the entire line.

```
function createPopup(text) {

  var text = [];
  var selection = DocumentApp.getActiveDocument().getSelection().getSelectedElements(); 

  if (selection) {
    for (var i = 0; i < selection.length; i++) {
      text.push(selection[i].getElement().asText().getText());
    }

  DocumentApp.getUi().alert(text);

  }    
}
```

Comment: I don't think this is possible. Do you have an example of a document or add-on where this is possible to do?

Comment: @RafaGuillermo I wanted to do something similar to the popup that comes when you click the hyperlink button after highlighting the target text. It turns the selected text blue, and a popup shows up.

Comment: I am looking for something similar. Just like the spelling suggestion tooltip.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Answer:

*Unfortunately, this is not possible.*

#### More Information:

[image]

The tool-tip-like pop-ups that show for hyperlinks such as this one are not customisable and not a feature that is currently in Google Sheets.

#### Workaround:

You can use comments on cells which act similarly to these tooltips: hovering over the cell will reveal the comment like so:

[image]

#### Feature Request:

Alternatively, if you would like something more customaible than cell comments, I would suggest filing a feature request to Google with the details.

You can do this from the Google Sheets UI, by following the `Help > Help Sheets improve` menu item.

There is also a feature request [here](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/36756650) which details being able to add and manipulate comments directly from Google Apps Script, so add a star to the issue to help its visibility.

Comment: The question was about Google DOCS (not Spreadhsheets).

Comment: @Paktas You're 2 years late to the party 